# Receiving SMS Messages using WMA in Java ME

Tags: java, java-me, sms, wma

I am trying to develop a sms sending and receiving test application in J2ME using the WMA API. I have separate threads for sending and receiving.

The Sending thread's run method -

```
public void run() {
        try {

            MessageConnection connection = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://+" + number + ":1234");
            BinaryMessage messageBody = (BinaryMessage) connection.newMessage(connection.BINARY_MESSAGE);
            messageBody.setPayloadData(message.getBytes());
            connection.send(messageBody);
            connection.close();


        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
```

The receiving thread's run method

```
public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                MessageConnection connection = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://:1234");
                BinaryMessage messageBody = (BinaryMessage) connection.receive();
                message = new String(messageBody.getPayloadData());
                number = messageBody.getAddress();
                number = number.substring(6, 15);
                App.setDisplay(number, message);
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

I am initializing the receiving thread in the startApp() and initializing the sending thread when the send command is pressed. The problem I have is that if I use two Emulators, both sides can't send messages. One emulator can continuously send messages to the other but when the other emulator tries to send a message the message isn't received.

When a message is received by the emulator console shows -

> [INFO] [sms     ] ## javacall: SMS
>   sending...

when that line appears the emulator doesn't receive any messages. Where is the problem in my code?

PS: I saw that their is a way to use a listener to work around this problem with using a separate thread for receiving but I want to know where is the problem is in the above code? 
Any help is really appreciated ^^

Comment: Just in case I am using Netbeans for development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... It's because SMS doesn't work in Netbeans above versions. It only works in Netbeans 6.1 ... Something is wrong with the emulator

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in emulator, use wma console available to send or receive messages. You can't do it from emulator to emulator. wma console is available at 
utilities -> wma console